# string replace multiple characters with a fullstop - Javascript

Tags: javascript

example:

```
string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit";
indices = [4,7,9,12,15];
output =  "Lore* *p*um*do*or sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit";
```

I want to replace character 5, 8, 10, 13 and 16 with a '*'. I did +1 because indices contains index. **how can I do that?**

Below code works just fine but only the last replaceAt in a for loop stays.
**I get : output =  "Lorem ipsum do*or sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit";**

## code

```
        var input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit";
        var indices = [], newIndices = [];
        for(var i=0; i<input.length;i++) {
            if (input[i] === " ") indices.push(i);
        }
        var totalIndices = indices.length;

        if(totalIndices >= 9){
            //new indices array
            for(var j=0; j<totalIndices;j+=4) {
                //indices.splice(j, 1);
                newIndices.push(indices[j]);
            }
            //Change spaces to full-stop
            for(var k=0; k<newIndices;k++) {
                input.replaceAt(newIndices[k], ".");
            }
        }else{
            input.split(" ").join('.');
        }
```

Comment: `indices.forEach(i => string[i] = '*');`

Comment: @Rajesh actually sorry I need to replace "SPACE" with "." check my code. can you tell me what should I replace this line with `input.replaceAt(newIndices[k], ".");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the indices array and reduce the splitted string by replacing the character at index.

```js
var string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit",
    indices = [4, 7, 9, 12, 15];
    result = indices.reduce(function (r, i) {
        r[i] = '*';
        return r;
    }, string.split('')).join('');

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit",
    indices = [4, 7, 9, 12, 15];
    result = Object.assign([...string], ...indices.map(i => ({ [i]: '*' }))).join('');

console.log(result);
```